# How do I turn on RTX

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders, lighting

So I feel this may be stupid but I just got a 3060 and would like to know how do I turn RTX on in blender. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Preferences and go to the System Tab.  Your graphics card should be listed under "Cycles Render Devices".  Enable it.  That's all you need.

Here's my Preferences.  I have a different graphics card, but yours should be listed where the highlight is in my screenshot:

[image: Preferences showing the graphics card highlighted in the System tab]

You probably also want to select "OptiX" rather than "CUDA" for your card.